# R debug errors on return statement

Tags: r

I'm writing a regex function in R that compares strings, but it is failing. When I attempt to debug it to see where it is failing, R appears to be interpreting return string contents as functions. I'm not really sure why this is the case, but I created the most simple version of the problem for reproducibility.

```
testfun<-function(data){
 if(data=='test')
  return('success')
 else return ('failure')
}

testdata<-'test'

testfun(testdata) 
[1] "success"
```

^So that works fine. When I want to run debug on such a function for a failure (which does not exist in thistest case, but does in my actual function), I receive the following output:

```
debug(testfun(testdata))
Error in debug(testfun(testdata)) : could not find function "success"
```

Is there something I'm missing here or documentation that I didn't see?

Comment: Try this instead:

    `debugonce(testfun);
    testfun(testdata)`

Comment: @creutzml, I don't know why this works, but it works. Any chance you have insight on what's going on here?

Comment: Honestly, I don't have much experience with using the base debug commands.But after reading the documentation, I think the debug command wants you to run it on the function first, then call the function to enter the debug state. I chose to use `debugonce` so that it doesn't enter debug on every function iteration.

Comment: I've also made this an official answer, so that others can edit it or comment on it, if they have more intuition on debugging in R

Comment: Nailed it. If I wrap debug around my function definition debug(testfun<-function{}) then call it testfun(testdata) I'm able to get into the browser. Please pop this down as an answer and I'll select it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug asks the user to call it on just the function name first. Then execute the function with the arguments to enter a debug mode. If you don't want it to enter debug on every execution of that function, then use `debugonce`. For example:

```
testfun<-function(data){
 if(data=='test')
  return('success')
 else return ('failure')
}

testdata<-'test'

debugonce(testfun)
testfun(testdata)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From this it looks like you're trying to output a string value of success or failure? 
Therefore should you not be using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Taken from examples here; https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/return-function

Comment: @RDKells r documentation indicates that strings can be defined as 'text', "text" or `text` 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html